# FluentNHibernate.dll Inner exception: The signature is incorrect

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

After following the steps outline in [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/161638-fluent-nhibernate-tutorial/) Fluent NHibernate tutorial I am stuck on the issue described below.

When I build and run the project I encounter the following error when attempting to build the session factory: "**An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail**".

The InnerException contains the following error message: "**...\bin\Debug\FluentNHibernate.dll] The signature is incorrect**" and the PotentialReasons collection has a lenght of 0. (nothing was added).

Here is the method:

```
  return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .ConnectionString(c =>
                    c.Server("CHRIS-PC\\SQLEXPRESS")
                    .Database("TestDB")
                    .Username("test")
                    .Password("test")))
                    .Mappings(m =>
                        m.AutoMappings.Add(model))
                        .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
                        .BuildSessionFactory();
```

I am using what I believe to be the latest version of the FluentNhibernate.dll (version 1.2).  I cannot seem to find anyone having a similar issue on the 'net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   return Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                                            .ConnectionString(@"Data Source=CHRIS-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDB;User ID=test"))
                                            .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(model))
                                            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
                                             .BuildSessionFactory();
```

or use this let **mymodel** be a sample **model**

```
 Fluently.Configure()
.Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
.ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CHRIS-PC\\SQLEXPRESS"].ConnectionString))
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<mymodel>().Add<UsersMap>())
.ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
{
new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false);
//    new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(true, true);
 }).BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: I am sorry to report that the first suggestion didn't work.  The error and its inner exception are the same as reported above.  Is it possible this is a trust or security issue between Windows 7 and this FluentNhibernate.dll?

Comment: But I am very pleased to report your second suggestion, slightly modified, did seem to work for me.  This is the snippet that finally got things working for me `return Fluently.Configure()
               .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
               .ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString))
               .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(model))
               .ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
               {
                   new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false);
               }).BuildSessionFactory();`